# How to escape this while-loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I wrote the following method, which boolean-return type is again assigned to another boolean in another method in which I call this method.

```
    private boolean answer() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean b = false;
    String answer = input.nextLine();

    while(answer != "y" || answer != "n") {
        System.out.println("Answer with y (yes) or n (no)");
        answer = input.nextLine();
    }
    if (answer == "y") {
        b = true;
    }
    return b;

}
```

But no matter what I type in (y, n, or any other letter), I always end up in the while-loop again.

Comment: Of course. Whatever you type it will be either different from y or different from n. 
You should try with && instead of ||.

Comment: I have answered your question. Please check it :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have an `or` rather than `and` on your test.

As it's currently coded you are saying:

> while the answer isn't "y" **or** it isn't "n", loop.

which will always be the case.

What you want is:

> while the answer isn't "y" **and** it isn't "n", loop.

which is coded as:

```
while (answer != "y" && answer != "n") (
```

Comment: Tried with && too, still the same result.

Comment: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/151206/te6sh3fa.png

(first line is from another method)

Comment: @Strict - the only other explanation is that the value `answer` isn't what you expect it to be. What do you get if you debug/print out the value of `answer`?

Comment: Printing out the answer is the same value I typed in. Maybe I should use a char variable instead of a String? Dunno.

Comment: Just compared my answer (y) to the actual value "y" via print out
System.out.println(answer == "y");

And the value is false. So though I type in y, y is != "y"

Comment: @Strict - you don't say what language you are using. it would help to know that so we can verify what type `input.nextLine` returns.

Comment: I'm using Java. 

If I do something like this in the main method:

String a = "y";
System.out.println(a == "y") it returns true.

It returns false through, if I type in the letter y through the Scanner.

So the crux lies in the Scanner.

Comment: @Strict - ask a **new** question about the behaviour of Scanner. Reference this one as context.

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:  `while(answer != "y" && answer != "n")` and your code will work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem lies here:
while(answer != "y" || answer != "n")

When your answer = "y" it isn't = "n" so the loop continues and vice verse.

Probably you want this:
while(answer != "y" && answer != "n")

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit to accept a char instead.

Here is the code:

```
private boolean answer() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean b = false;

    char answer = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

    while(answer != 'y' || answer != 'n' ) {
        System.out.println("Answer with y (yes) or n (no)");
        //lower case so that it will get y or n, no matter what the casing is
        answer = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    }
    if (answer == 'y') {
        b = true;
    }
    return b;

}
```

or if you really want a string

```
private boolean answer() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean b = false;
    String answer = input.nextLine();

    while( !(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) ) {
        System.out.println("Answer with y (yes) or n (no)");
        answer = input.nextLine();
    }
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        b = true;
    }
    return b;
}
```

> Remember to use **.equals()** or **.equalsIgnoreCase()** when comparing two Strings